# Should I use underscore function in node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, underscore.js, blocking

I have 3 tasks running parallel. In the first task, I use underscore method to loop through an array(for example _.each ). Does that underscore method block the other 2 tasks? If so, isn't it a bad idea to use underscore module in node.js?

Comment: If you need to loop over an array and do x, where x is synchronous, it's going to block the other two tasks regardless of what tool you use to do the looping, unless you move it to another node process entirely. underscore's each method isn't the problem.

Comment: Are those tasks asynchronous? What kind of routines are you calling?

Comment: @KevinB: what do you mean with "unless you move it to another node process entirely"? In other words, what is "another node process"?

Comment: childprocess.spawn() for example. It literally starts a second node.js app on the side, in a separate thread.

Comment: @apendua: Yes, all all thoes 3 tasks are asynchronous. Let me explain a little bit more. I am developing an API using keystone.js, My API has to deal with a lot of requests, which need as few synchronous functions  as possible. This is the reason why I am hesitating to use underscore. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MrCold yes, that would be a wrong case to think about not using underscore.

Comment: Underscore has nothing to do with this problem at all. All javascript code you run, underscore or not, will block the thread while running. The key is for it to run very quickly and finish very quickly, as to not block the thread long enough for it to matter. Even something as simple as `var x = Date.now()` will block the thread and cause problems, if ran enough times in a single loop.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you have a problem related to blocking the thread. If you do, please provide the code that does it.

Comment: @KevinB but you said that "it's going to block the other two tasks", so these 2 tasks will have to wait until the first task finish? Does it make the program run slowlier? Ok, let me tell about my API. For example, my API has to do with 3 http requests almost at the same time. If I use a underscore function (synchronous function) somewhere in my API code, when this underscore function runs, for example when processing the first request, do the other tasks dealing with request 2 and request 3 has to stop and wait until underscore function stop to continue running?

Comment: No matter what code you use, the three requests will be handled one at a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87215/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-mr-cold).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it blocks. No, it has nothing to do with using underscore.

Javascript is single threaded. When you register a bunch of event handlers or setTimeouts, they do NOT run in parallel - each one runs until it gets back to the event loop, then another one is pulled off the event queue and executed.

If your array is huge and you need to do a bunch of synchronous work on each element, you'll probably want to split up the work across multiple turns of the event loop. However, if it's reasonably small then it probably won't matter.

This has nothing to do with underscore, this is just the nature of Javascript.